# C what is wrong with function?

Tags: c, avr, servo

Hi i have problem with function to control my 4servos. I want to take this code to function but it's not working.

```
volatile float servo1;

            variable=  uart_getchar();
            _delay_ms(100);
            variable=variable/10;
            servo1=variable;
            sprintf(bufor,"Servo_1= %4.1f\n",servo1);
            uart_puts(bufor);
```

when this code is not in function everything is okay, servo works good. Problem is when i do this:

```
void get(float Servo, char Number)
{
            variable=  uart_getchar();
            _delay_ms(100);
            variable=variable/10;
            Servo=variable;
            sprintf(bufor,"Serwo_%c= %4.1f\n",Number,Servo);
            uart_puts(bufor);
}
```

and when i call `get(servo1,'1');`servo stayed in the same place all the time.. any idea what is wrong??

Comment: Do you know what `void f(int x) {x = 5;} int main() {int y = 7; f(y); printf("%i\n", y); return 0;}` prints? (in normal C, not AVR)

Comment: I think i know its 5

Comment: @Mateusz It prints 7, because `x` is a different variable from `y`, and `x = 5;` changes `x`, not `y`.

Comment: So what will be the solution for this?

Comment: `void f(int* x) {*x = 5;} int main() {int y = 7; f(&y); printf("%i\n", y); return 0;}`

Comment: @adminXVII Post that as an answer.

Comment: 1)  the variable: `variable`, is not declared. 2) if `variable` is not a float, then this line: `variable=variable/10;` will perform a integer divide, probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change a variable you passed to a function, you must use [pointers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm).

Basically it's used like this:

```
void f(int* x){
  *x = 5;
}

int main() {
  int y = 7;
  f(&y);
  printf("%i\n", y);
  return 0;
}
```

In short, `&` get the address of the variable and `*` get the value at the address

Comment: @Mateusz,  if you like the answer, then 'select' it so this question will close AND `admin XVII` will be properly credited for the answer